# Not all font and colour schemas are selectable in Kate

Tags: fonts, configuration, colors, kate

On my Kate configuration directory (~/.local/share/org.kde.syntax-highlighting/syntax/) I have files such as: octave.xml, opencl.xml, orgmode.xml, ...

However I have no way to see them when trying to configure Kate. From Settings/Configure Kate/Font & Colour Schemas, Highlight Text Styles, I have a subset of the possible configurations, but some are missing (e.g. orgmode).

Is it normal that those XML configuration files are in my home directory only, and not in Kate's own directory?

How can I tell Kate to look for XML configuration files in other, non-default, directories?